# merge 2 array with specific element

Tags: php, arrays

let say that i have 2 arrays like this

Array Question :

```
array (size=4)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => string '4'
      'question' => string 'what food do you like?'
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => string '5'
      'question' => string 'where do you want to go?'
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => string '6'
      'question' => string 'are you busy?'
  3 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => string '7'
      'question' => string 'are you enjoy the party?'
```

and second array is Answer array :

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => string '4'
      'answer' => string 'burger'
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => string '5'
      'answer' => string 'go to mall'
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => string '6'
      'answer' => string 'no im not'
```

how to i can merge that 2 array become like this

```
id : 4
question : 'what food do you like?'
answer : 'burger'

id : 5
question : 'where do you want to go?'
answer : 'go to mall'

id : 6
question : 'are you busy?'
answer : 'no im not'

id : 7
question : 'are you enjoy the party?'
answer : ''
```

i need to add answer '' (emtpy) if it not answer for some question. how do i can merge that array

Answer (score 1):

This code will give you the result you want. For each question it looks to see if there is an answer in the answers array. If there is, it pushes the id, question and answer, otherwise it just pushes the id and question and a blank answer into the result array. Note that it uses somewhat paranoid code (the use of `array_combine` on the keys and values of `$answers`) but this means that it works regardless of the order of values in `$questions` and `$answers`:

```
$questions = array (
    array (
      'id' =>  '4',
      'question' =>  'what food do you like?'),
    array (
      'id' =>  '6',
      'question' =>  'are you busy?'),
    array (
      'id' =>  '5',
      'question' =>  'where do you want to go?'),
    array (
      'id' =>  '7',
      'question' =>  'are you enjoy the party?')
    );

$answers = array (
    array (
      'id' =>  '6',
      'answer' =>  'no im not'),
    array (
      'id' =>  '4',
      'answer' =>  'burger'),
    array (
      'id' =>  '5',
      'answer' =>  'go to mall')
    );

$qanda = array();
foreach ($questions as $question) {
    $id = $question['id'];
    $akey = array_search($id, array_combine(array_keys($answers), array_column($answers, 'id')));
    $qanda[] = array('id' => $id,
                     'question' => $question['question'],
                     'answer' => ($akey !== false) ? $answers[$akey]['answer'] : '');
}
print_r($qanda);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [question] => what food do you like?
            [answer] => burger
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [question] => where do you want to go?
            [answer] => go to mall
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [question] => are you busy?
            [answer] => no im not
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [question] => are you enjoy the party?
            [answer] => 
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can be use this simple code:

```
$arrayFirst = array(
    0 => array('id' => '4', 'question' => 'what food do you like?'),
    1 => array('id' => '5', 'question' => 'where do you want to go?'),
    2 => array('id' => '6', 'question' => 'are you busy?'),
    3 => array('id' => '7', 'question' => 'are you enjoy the party?')
);

$arraySecond = array(
    0 => array('id' => '4', 'answer' => 'burger'),
    1 => array('id' => '5', 'answer' => 'go to mall'),
    2 => array('id' => '6', 'answer' => 'no im not')
);

$arrayThird = array();

foreach ($arrayFirst as $key => $value) {

    $arrayThird[$key] = $value;
   if (isset($arraySecond[$key])) {

    $arrayThird[$key]['answer'] = $arraySecond[$key]['answer'];

}else{

    $arrayThird[$key]['answer'] = "";

}
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($arrayThird);
```

Output

```
   Array
    (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [question] => what food do you like?
            [answer] => burger
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [question] => where do you want to go?
            [answer] => go to mall
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [question] => are you busy?
            [answer] => no im not
        )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [id] => 7
                [question] => are you enjoy the party?
                [answer] => 
         )

    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply iterate over array then check the question id against answer id, push matched set in new array.

```
  $qList = array
  (
  array("id"=>"1", "question"=>"What is your name?"),
  array("id"=>"2", "question"=>"What is your age?"),
  array("id"=>"3", "question"=>"What is your hobbies?")
  );

$aList = array
  (
  array("id"=>"1", "answer"=>"tjandra"),
  array("id"=>"2", "answer"=>"..."),
);


$final = array();
foreach($qList as $x => $x_value) {
  $qId = $x_value["id"];
  $aFound = false;
   foreach($aList as $ans => $ans_value) {
       $aId = $ans_value["id"];
        if($aId == $qId){
            $aFound = true;
            $innerCont = array();
            $innerCont["id"] = $aId;
            $innerCont["question"] = $x_value["question"];
            $innerCont["answer"] = $ans_value["answer"];
            array_push($final,  $innerCont);
            break;
         }
   }
   if(!$aFound) {
            $innerCont = array();
            $innerCont["id"] = $aId;
            $innerCont["question"] = $x_value["question"];
            $innerCont["answer"] = "";
            array_push($final,  $innerCont);

   }
}
var_dump($final);
```